# Replacing elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following jquery markup:

```
<p class="article">
    <font size='5'><b><span class='articleHeading'>Article1</span></b></font><br/>
    <span class='myArticle'>11111111111111111</span>    
</p>
<p class="article">
    <font size='5'><b><span class='articleHeading'>Article2</span></b></font><br/>
    <span class='myArticle'>22222222222222222222</span>                      
</p>
<p class="article">
    <font size='5'><b><span class='articleHeading'>Article3</span></b></font><br/>
    <span class='myArticle'>333333333333</span>                                   
</p>
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate over json data (which works successfully), and put
new data inside the spans of classes 'articleHeading' and 'article':

I tried this:

```
     var articleHeadings=$('.articleHeading');
                var articles=$('.myArticle');
                var z=0;
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    var obj = data[i];

                    for(var key in obj){
                        ArticleHeadings[z].text(key);
                        articles[z].text(obj[key]);
                        z++;
                    }
                }
```

I updated my question. I am puttin all my spans into 2 array..heading and the article..and then using them..but it doesnt work

```
 //I want to obtain all the spans with the classes elements and put them in 2 arrays.
  var articleHeadings=$('.articleHeading');
   var articles=$('.myArticle');
   //I want to add text to the first element like this.                
                    articleHeadings[0].text("1111111111");
//There is an element inside..but when using text nothing appears.
```

But when I use this:

```
$('.articleHeading').text("1111111111");
```

The 11111 do get replaced..lol. Why? is it because there is a shallow copy by value? instead of by reference?

I found the solution. I had to wrap each item of my array with $():

```
          var articleHeadings=$('.articleHeading');
                var articles=$('.myArticle');




                var z=0;
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    var obj = data[i];

                    for(var key in obj){

                    //  alert($(articleHeadings[z]).text());
                       **$(articleHeadings[z]).text(key);**
                       **$(articles[z]).text(obj[key]);**
                        z++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `I have teh following jquery markup` None of this is jQuery.

Comment: is the html precreated and same length of p's as the data, or would you rather make the HTML dynamically as the articles are found in data? because i can show you how to do either

Comment: I updated my answer..I want to swap anything in the spans with new content..

Comment: I haven't seen a `<font>` tag in like 10 years.

Comment: lol..I was rushing, I didnt care. Could you help me ..I am close the solution..why I cant store the elments on the page into an array and then replace each elements text?

Comment: How do u pass jquery by reference?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your JSON looks something like this:

```
$data = {
    "data": [{
        "articleHeading": "First heading",
        "myArticle": "First article body"},
    {
        "articleHeading": "Second heading",
        "myArticle": "Second article body"},
    {
        "articleHeading": "Third heading",
        "myArticle": "Third article body"}]
};
```

Your jQuery would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.each($data.data, function(i, data){
        var $article = $('.article').eq(i);
        $article.find('.articleHeading').html(data.articleHeading);
        $article.find('.myArticle').html(data.myArticle); 
    ​});
});
```

​
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lujew/

Comment: I found a more elegant solution..all I had to do was to wrap $(itemelment[0])... when an item of my array is wrapped..It then works.. look at the solutioin above. your solution is a nice solution too

Comment: very nice, much more sleek, as i mentioned there are several ways

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could go about this, the easiest would probably be to create a div where you want the articles, clear it then fill based on data entering in, so that you could do this dynamically via ajax and refresh it every few seconds or what ever.

For instance you might could do it like so:

```
$("#divID").empty();
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var attrName, value;
    for(var key in data[i]){
        attrName = key;
        value = data[i][key];  
    }
    $("#divID").append(
        $("<p />").addClass("article").append(
            $("<span />").addClass("articleHeading").text(attrName),
            $("<span />").addClass("myArticle").text(value)
        )
    )
}
```

then use css to handle the font size and bold and such

```
.articleHeading {
    font-size: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: i'll break this down when i get back from lunch if you still need more explination

Comment: it will wreak a havoc if I do that. I tried inserting values that way..It doesnt work. elements are all over the place. The problem that I am experiencing, is described above